# How to hide a specific active app on OS Sonama (Version 14.1.1)

Tags: macos

Is there a way to hide a running app in OS Sonama but said app won't appear in force quit or in docks.

I know there was a way in earlier OS by editing Info.plist file but that method longer works on newer OS (app crashes/doesn't launch/cant edit info.plist)

Comment: Setting LSUIElement to true in the Info.plist should still work, however Sonoma is going to want you to codesign the app.

Comment: @RichardBarber thanks for the suggestion. What's codesign ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html

Comment: Also this was 100% a programming question, should not have been migrated to su.